# Let the user know page is loading

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with a page i have. The page is used to display performance statistics.
It has a gridview and uses a MySql server datasource. When loading the page the query to fill the page takes about 30s to 2 min. During this the users sees a white blank page. Is there a way to load the masterpage and show the user that the page is loading ?

Here's the page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="BSC1" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BSC1_all.aspx.cs" Inherits="Estat.BSC1.BSC1_all" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <h2>BSC1 Allar Cellur</h2>
        <h2 align="center">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></h2><br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="cell" DataSourceID="gull_bsc1" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center" CellPadding="3">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cella" SortExpression="cell" FooterText="Cella">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cell") %>'>  </asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("cell","http://intra/OneCellBSC1/OneCellBSC1.aspx?cell={0}") %>'
                    Target="_blank"><%# Eval("cell") %></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ph_traffic" HeaderText="PH Traffic" 
            SortExpression="ph_traffic" FooterText="PH Traffic" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ph_fravisun" HeaderText="PH Frávísanir" 
            SortExpression="ph_fravisun" FooterText="PH Frávísanir" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ph_slit" HeaderText="PH Slit" 
            SortExpression="ph_slit" FooterText="PH Slit" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="avg_traffic" HeaderText="Meðaltals Traffic" 
            SortExpression="avg_traffic" FooterText="Meðaltals Traffic" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sum_fravisun" HeaderText="Samtals Frávísanir" 
            SortExpression="sum_fravisun" FooterText="Samtals Frávísanir" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sum_slit" HeaderText="Samtals Slit" 
            SortExpression="sum_slit" FooterText="Samtals Slit" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="gull_bsc1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gull_agg_bsc1 %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gull_agg_bsc1.ProviderName %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT cell, ph_traffic, ph_fravisun, ph_slit, avg_traffic, sum_fravisun, sum_slit FROM bsc1_aggregete_cell_to_day WHERE timi_tolfraedi LIKE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)" 
    CacheDuration="86400" EnableCaching="True">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use AJAX to load the report **asynchronously**. This way, your page loads fast, and user can interact with it, then the report gets loaded **without** blocking user.

However, I have an explanation for you to know why user sees nothing in your case. AMAIK, when a user comes to your page, his/her browser sends an HTTP Request to your page, which means that your server in response sends an HTML document (in this case) or any other Internet Media Type (MIME Type), like a file to download, a CSS file, an image, etc.

Browser then starts downloading server's response. However, most browsers won't show a document, until it's completed (I don't know about streaming that much, in which browsers get a chunck of data, and show it back, then another chunk, and show it back, and so on).

This means that, while your grid is loading data from the database, the HTML data sent back to user is not complete, thus browser can not render it, thus user sees a blank page.

Also you should notice that all the stuff downloaded in an HTTP request, are downloaded **synchronously**, that is, they block user from using the web page, while they're getting downloaded. For example, if you have a web page with 10 large images, you usually can't interact with page, while those images get downloaded.

What you try to do, is a necessity in a concept called **dashboard**, in which, many reports are gathered together from millions (or billions) of records of database. Dashboards take a long time to fetch data. Therefore, a common practice for showing dashboards, is to send a simple page to user, which contains many placeholders, then loading the contents of those placeholders **asynchronously** using AJAX technology.

Comment: Do I need to redesign the whole thing or is there a simple way to add async with this ?